# how can i change initializing collection of backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, marionette, backbone-views

I have HAML template like this

```
%body
:javascript
  (function() {
   .....
    this.App = new Ex({
      currentUser: #{current_user.to_json},
      recentFolders: #{{"next_page"=>2,"folders"=>@recent_folders.as_json}.to_json},
      rootUrl: "#{root_url}",
      env: "#{Rails.env}"
    });
    $(this.App.start);
  }).call(this);
```

and backbone view

```
class FoldersView extends Marionette.CompositeView
template: JST['views/dashboard/folders']
className: 'h-folders'
itemView: FoldersItemView
itemViewContainer: '.b-folders'

ui:
  more: '.b-more'

events:
  'click .more' : 'showMoreFolders'

showMoreFolders: ->
  @collection.fetchNext()
  @ui.more.prop('hidden', 'hidden') if @collection.isLastPage
```

backbone model

```
class Folders.Collection extends Backbone.Collection
model: Folders.Model

url: "/api/folders"

initialize: (models) ->
  console.log models

parse: (response) ->
  @nextPage = response.meta['next_page']
  response.folders

fetchNext: ->
  @fetch add:true, data: {page: @nextPage}, success: => @_success

isLastPage: ->
  unless @nextPage
    true

_success: ->
  @trigger('fetch')

module.exports = Folders
```

Problem with pagination. When clicked link "see more"(showMoreFolders method) it fetches collection by pagination(if page=2 get seconds page and so on) from server and shows in a view. When first time rendered HAML with inline JS code params[:page] of fetchNext method is @undefined@.

How can i include next_page at first time when rtendered HAML with inline JS?

Before thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model.parse only gets called after the fetch and save methods execute. On initial load neither of those get called so Model.parse never runs. You either need to initialize your @nextPage property to something in the model definition or come up with a way to bootstrap that data into your model. Initializing it in the model is definitely easier, and keeps the module specific data isolated from the rest of your app.

```
initialize: (models) ->
  @setNextPage(2)

parse: (response) ->
  @setNextPage(response.meta['next_page'])

setNextPage: (page) ->
  @nextPage = page
```